# How to wait for asynchronous callback in the background (i.e. not invoked by us)

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, python-asyncio, tws

Goal is to allocate a thread and wait for the callback. Single thread is going to run the while loop forever. Difficulty here is that we are not directly calling or controlling the callback and we do not know in advance how long it will takes to the remote server to invoke callback.

I've tried to look for a solution in the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task) module using `asyncio.Future` but unsuccessfully.

```
from a_module import Server  # <a_module> is fictitious
import random
import time


class App(Server):
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = None

    def send_requests(self):
        """Send request to remote server"""
        self.send_number_to_server(42)  # inherited from Server

        # This is going to loop forever. We should "suspend" the 
        # current thread, allocate a new thread to wait for the
        # callback and then comeback here to return the (not None) 
        # response.
        while self.response is None:
            # Wait for the callback before terminating this method.
            time.sleep(1)  # seconds
        return self.response


    def callback(self, message):
        """Inherited form parent class 'Server'. When the request sent
        with App.send_req has been processed by the remote server,
        this function is invoked in the background."""
        self.response = message


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    response = app.send_requests()
    print(response)
```

Comment: So just to make sure I understand what you are trying to achieve: when you call `send_requests` you want to perform some work asynchronously and wait for its completion and return result? What is the problem you are trying to solve in general? Because just doing some work asynchronously the way you want now will still block main thread, since you are waiting for response, and you won't be able to submit more requests.

Answer (score 1):

Since `callback` is "invoked in the background", `Server` is presumably already running a background thread. In that case, you want your main thread to run the event loop, and the server's background thread to notify you when it is done. Assuming `send_number_to_server` is not blocking, you could do it like this:

```
class App(Server):
    def __init__(self):
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    async def send_requests(self):
        self.send_number_to_server(42)
        self._future_resp = asyncio.Future()
        resp = await self._future_resp
        self._future_resp = None
        return resp

    def callback(self, message):
        # called from a different thread
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self._future_resp.set_result, message)

async def main():
    app = App()
    response = await app.send_requests()
    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```